# How do I query for Strings containing a letter more than once?

Tags: mysql, string

How do I run a query in MySQL to search for Strings containing a character on more than one occurrence?

`SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name LIKE '%r%'` will only return animals that contain an 'r'..

```
+---------+------------+
|    id   | name       |
+---------+------------+
|     1   | zebra      |
|     14  | raccoon    |
|     25  | parrot     | 
|     49  | rhinoceros |
+---------+------------+
```

`SELECT * FROM animals WHERE name LIKE '%rr%'` will only return animals that contain an occurance of 'rr'..

```
+---------+------------+
|    id   | name       |
+---------+------------+
|     25  | parrot     | 
+---------+------------+
```

I would like to find any animal names that contain an 'r'.. lets say twice anywhere in the name.

```
+---------+------------+
|    id   | name       |
+---------+------------+
|     25  | parrot     | 
|     49  | rhinoceros |
+---------+------------+
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
select *
from animals
where name like '%r%r%'
```

An alternative solution is to use length and replace:

```
select *
from animals
where length(name) - length(replace(name, 'r', '')) >= 2;
```

This could be advantageous if you were looking for occurrences of a set of letters, for instance `'r'` and `'s`':

```
select *
from animals
where length(name) - length(replace(replace(name, 'r', ''), 's', '')) >= 2;
```

EDIT:

If you want *exactly* two "r"s, you can just use equality in the `where` clause:

```
select *
from animals
where length(name) - length(replace(name, 'r', '')) = 2;
```

Comment: The LIKE solution isn't quite the same as the question asked of the REPLACE() solution, because it matches names with 2 *or more* "r" chars. You'd have to add `AND NOT LIKE '%r%r%r%'` or switch to using regex to find *exactly* 2.

Comment: @Bohemian . . . The question is ambiguous.  It says "contain an 'r'.. lets say twice anywhere in the name".  Out of context, your interpretation would be the more reasonable.  But, the context is that 'parrot' matched the case with 1 'r'.

Comment: Thought you might like to add it in as an alternative, in case future people do want exactly 2. It's an interesting solution I haven't seen before. It still stands that the two versions will not produce the same results unless by chance there are no names with more than 2 r's - that at least should be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can go about it indirectly, by checking how much a string's length changes when you REMOVE those characters:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM yourtable
WHERE (length(name) - length(replace(name, 'r', ''))) >= 2
```

e.g. parrot has 6 chars, and with the `r` removed, is only 4, so 6-4=2 and would match the where.